# How to get debian packages from older releases

Tags: package, debian, release, deb, mirror

This might be one basic question.
but I wanted to download packages of specific debian version from debian mirror.

e.g I wanted to download debian 9.11 packages but when I checked on debian mirror(http://ftp.debian.com/debian/dists/)

I could see only debian 9.12 entry and no entry of 9.11
[screenshot of debian mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bffNJ.png)

I know debian must archive these packages and mirror somewhere else but I am currently not able to find it

Once a developer told that he used jigdo images to get the archived mirror. But I am not able to extract debian mirror url from jigdo images

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I after searching over the internet, I got the solution.

I found mirror url from jidgo image uploaded by debian.

I downloaded jidgo image of debian 9.11 from here
https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/9.11.0/amd64/iso-cd/

and used zcat command on .jidgo file and found mirror at the end of the file
the mirror was something like this
http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20190909T181138Z/